# Chrome browser: GET favicon.ico each time an audio object is played

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker, html5-audio

I have a sound like this:

```
var sound_obj = document.createElement("audio");
sound_obj.src = "../sounds/clic.mp3";
sound_obj.volume = 0.10;
sound_obj.autoPlay = false;
sound_obj.preLoad = true;
sound_obj.type = 'audio/mpeg';

document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    sound_obj.play();
});
```

Everything is working well on all browsers. But in Chrome I see that every time I click, Chrome is asking for favicon.ico from site. Every time. What I am doing wrong?

```
GET "https://mysite/favicon.ico".
```

**LATER EDIT**

It seems to be related by using a service worker ('fetch'). This is my version:

```
const VERSION = 10;
const CACHE_NAME = 'mysite-cache-v-' + VERSION;

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  // Let the browser do its default thing
  // for non-GET requests.
  if (event.request.method != 'GET') return;

  // Prevent the default, and handle the request ourselves.
  event.respondWith(async function() {
    // Try to get the response from a cache.
    const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
    const cachedResponse = await cache.match(event.request);

    if (cachedResponse) {
      // If we found a match in the cache, return it, but also
      // update the entry in the cache in the background.
      event.waitUntil(cache.add(event.request));
      console.log("cache fetch");
      return cachedResponse;
    }
    console.log("fresh fetch "+ event.request.url);
    // If we didn't find a match in the cache, use the network.
    return fetch(event.request, {credentials: 'same-origin', redirect: 'manual'});
  }());
});
```

In Firefox everything is OK, But in Chrome I see that browser is fetching `favicon.ico` at every click. If I bypass service worker in Chrome by using `Bypass for network`, everything is working fine. I have no clue what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in Chrome.
You can find the reference here:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1069731&q=favicon&can=2

You can see it in action on this Mozilla page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio